# Replace negative values in single DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1, 2,  3],
                         'B':[4, -5,  6],
                         'C':[7,  8, -9]}, 
                          index=pd.to_datetime(['2017-01-01 00:01:00', '2017-01-01 00:02:00', '2017-01-02 00:01:00']))

>>> df_1
                      A   B   C
2017-01-01 00:01:00  -1   4   7
2017-01-01 00:02:00   2  -5   8
2017-01-02 00:01:00   3   6  -9
```

How would I replace all of the negative values in a specific column with something else? For example, if I want to replace all of the negative values in the 'B' column but none of the others with, say 0, the following would be my result.

```
>>> df_2
                      A   B   C
2017-01-01 00:01:00  -1   4   7
2017-01-01 00:02:00   2   0   8
2017-01-02 00:01:00   3   6  -9
```

Comment: Does `df_1['B'][df_1['B'] < 0] = 0` work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can using `mask`

```
df_1.B=df_1.B.mask(df_1.B.lt(0),0)
df_1
Out[1437]: 
                     A  B  C
2017-01-01 00:01:00 -1  4  7
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  0  8
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6 -9
```

If we combine with `fillna` ()Assuming different columns should fill will different value)

```
df_1.mask(df_1.lt(0)).fillna({'A':9999,'B':0,'C':-9999})
Out[1440]: 
                          A    B       C
2017-01-01 00:01:00  9999.0  4.0     7.0
2017-01-01 00:02:00     2.0  0.0     8.0
2017-01-02 00:01:00     3.0  6.0 -9999.0
```

Answer (score 9):

If the values in column B are to be replaced with 0:

`df_1.loc[df_1['B']<0,'B']=0`

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.where for this. Add the following to your code to change values of column B for example:

```
df_1.B = np.where(df_1.B < 0, 0, df_1.B)

print(df_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, very similar to what @bhansa 's answer was going for, but using [`pandas.Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```
df_1.B[df_1.B.lt(0)] = 0

>>> df_1
                     A  B  C
2017-01-01 00:01:00 -1  4  7
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  0  8
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6 -9
```

Answer (score -2):

Normal conditional will work for you:

```
df_1[df_1['B'] < 0] = 0


                     A  B   C
2017-01-01 00:01:00 -1  4   7
2017-01-01 00:02:00  2  0   8
2017-01-02 00:01:00  3  6   -9
```

Comment: This will not work, I believe. If I understand correctly, this will mask the second row, then set all of the entries in that row to 0, instead of just the 'B' column.

Comment: `df_1['B'][df_1['B'] < 0] = 0` would fix it